# Linq - How to take the result for a query in Linq and add it to an Array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I use c#, linq and EF4 I would like ask your help.

My question:
I have a linq query, but i need the result for this query be inserted in an array string.
Value added should be Title and ContentId (ContentId from EF is an INT but i need it as a string)

Please let me know, many thanks in advances!PS: Please post the full code :-)

```
       public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, string count)
{
    using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
    {
    var queryTitle = (from content in context.CmsContents
                      select new
                      {
                          Title = content.Title, // String
                          ContentId = content.ContentId.ToString() // Int
                      }).ToArray();
    return queryTitle;


    }
```

Comment: You want to output an array of strings? or an array of the anonymous type defined?

Comment: Seeing that your query returns many rows, do you want to get a sequence (`IEnumerable`) of `string[]` arrays? Do you want to get some single value? Please explain.

Comment: Do you want just a single array of strings? In that case, how should the Title and ContentID be arranged in that single string? If you just want to convert the ContentId use "content.ContentId.ToString()".

Comment: What do you mean? Should a single string for each item contain both fields then? If you fail to explain your question to those who don't know your task (pretty much all of us), we'll just waste time.

Comment: Should be a single string for each item contain both fields. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have ContentId as a string, then do this:

```
var queryTitle = (from content in context.CmsContents
                 select new
                 {
                     Title = content.Title, // String
                     ContentId = content.ContentId.ToString() // Int
                 }).ToArray();
```

queryTitle will be an array of the anonymous type created, which has two properties:

1. Title
2. ContentId

Both of type string.

If you don't want to have an array of the anonymous type, but an array of strings, then use this code:

```
var queryTitles = (from content in context.CmsContents
                 select "Title: " + content.Title + ", ContentId: " +  content.ContentId.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi please look at my code update i receive an error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'string[]'

Comment: See my update to my answer. I added a second possibility, which should suit your needs better.

Comment: @Glbbok, it's because this code selects an anonymous typefor each item. If you want a string per item, please explain how an item should be transformed into string.

Comment: @Daniel, I'd go with `string.Format` instead.

Comment: Should be a single string for each item contain both fields. thanks

Comment: @gaearon: You could do that also, sure. Normally, I type it like this and use ReSharper to change it to string.Format. I don't have R# in the text box here ;-)

Comment: @GIbboK: I hope you realize, that the answer you now accepted, doesn't conform to your specification?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, was a mistake, I approved your anwer now :-) thanks

Comment: I still think that `string.Format` looks *way* better. You don't need to concat strings or explicitly call `ToString`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104907/linq-how-to-take-the-result-for-a-query-in-linq-and-add-it-to-an-array/5105127#5105127 for example

Comment: You don't have to explicitly call ToString in my code either. I just added it for clarity, that it is indeed a string. It can safely be removed. It's no difference, really. Just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to have contentID and Title in one big array of string (from your question, it sounds like that but not very clear), you might want to try this

```
var resultArray = titlesAsArray
            .Select(a => new[]
                             {
                                 a.ContentId.ToString(), a.Title
                             })
            .SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

or to modifiy your original query

```
var resultArray = context.CmsContents.Select(content => new[]
                                 {
                                     content.ContentId.ToString(), content.Title
                                 }).SelectMany(content => content).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think using `List` is unnecessary here.

Comment: This doesn't conform to his specification: "Should be a single string for each item contain both fields".

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = from content in context.CmsContents
              select string.Format ("{0} {1}",
                  content.ContentId,
                  content.Title
              );
```

That should help you.
Note that it's a common misconception that you need an array to work with query results—in fact, you don't, the result is already `IEnumerable`. If you're sure that you need an array, just wrap query in parentheses and call `ToArray` extension method on the result.